# XCode 7.3.1 membership issue

Tags: xcode7

Hello this morning my XCode had some problems...

[image]

I tried several times the "Sign in Again..." button but nothing has changed.

If I try to enter a wrong password (just to try if is a password mismatch) I get the message of wrong password

[image]

I'm able to login on the Apple Developer site with my password, and see that my membership is still valid:

[image]

(For your information, I still use XCode 7.3.1 and don't want to migrate to version 8, I still prefer to wait a few weeks. I restarted both XCode and the Mac but nothing has changed.)

Comment: Did you enabled two factor authorization?

Comment: You are the man, Philip, thank you so much ! After logout and logon on the Mac Book, and enabling the two factor authorization through sms on telephone, XCode has accepted the password and everything is ok now !